# mootools image enlarge on mouse hover plugin

Tags: javascript, animation, mootools

I am looking for a mootools plugin which will enlarge image on mouseover over the current image. So when a user is hovering on a image user feel the image is enlarged. Very close to my requirements were http://highslide.com/. Here is a sample I found http://jsfiddle.net/Jmeks/2/. I need exactly like this using mootools with some mootools effect. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: why can't you just do this with CSS3? do you need the effect to be cross browser compatible?

Comment: @Asad it need to be cross browser compatible

Answer (score 2):

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Jmeks/29/) fiddle work for you?
EDIT: I have changed the link so that it uses the transform css property as you required.

**JavaScript:**

```
window.myFx = new Fx({
        duration: 300,
        transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut
});
myFx.set = function(value) {
        var style = "scale(" + (value) + ")";
        $('content-block').setStyles({
            "-webkit-transform": style,
            "-moz-transform": style,
            "-o-transform": style,
            "-ms-transform": style,
            transform: style
        });
    }
$('content-block').addEvent('mouseover', function() {
    myFx.start(1,1.4);
});
$('content-block').addEvent('mouseout', function() {
    myFx.start(1.4,1);
});
```

Comment: Asad thanks for your help. You see the solution with css3 it scales the image to 1.4 I need something like that.

Comment: Asad as I mentioned previously it has to be browser compatible. I see some of the ecommerce sites were doing this where images pops up but unfortunately I can't remember those else I could do that by myself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It was browser compatible before I used the css3, which you specifically requested. If you don't want to use css3, you may use the [earlier example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jmeks/11/) I provided.